# Compiler says that \hbar is invalid in math mode, but I can't figure out what I should be using instead -- all the sources say \hbar?

Tags: errors

The line is

`$E = \frac{\hbar^2}{2I}J(J+1)$`

and the error code is "LaTeX Warning: Command \hbar invalid in math mode on input line 55."

Current packages: gensymb, amsmath, csquotes, placeins, cite, hanging, fontspec, graphicx, tikz, pgfplots

Comment: Please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the error message you quote. If I use the following example, I can't reproduce the error message you get. `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gensymb, amsmath, csquotes, placeins, cite, hanging, fontspec, graphicx, tikz, pgfplots}
\begin{document}
$E = \frac{\hbar^2}{2I}J(J+1)$
\end{document}`

Comment: I am also unable to reproduce the issue you say you're experiencing, using just the information you've provided so far.

Comment: Like this?

```\documentclass{article}      % Specifies the document class


\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}


\begin{document}

$E = \frac{\hbar^2}{2I}J(J+1)$

\end{document}```

I'm still getting the error.

Comment: That example works fine for me. I suspect something in your document is redefining `\hbar`. Here is a test: the compiler is complaining about line 55. So, on line 54, put `\show\hbar` and try to compile. What is the result?

Comment: Do you still need help with this? If so, please post an example that reproduces the problem and/or answer my question regarding the result of `\show\hbar`. Without more information, this question cannot be answered and is likely to be closed.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the error cannot be reproduced using the information provided. The OP has not responded to requests for further information in the comments.

Comment: Sorry I'm still here. I got sidetracked by another project and didn't get email notifications for some reason. Adding \show\hbar didn't change anything -- it didn't show anything in the document, and didn't trigger an error. I tried reposting an example that reproduced the issue but it only did it on my end so I don't know what else to do.

Comment: LaTeX can be horrible with errors and error logs. It is more than possible that the problem is either with something else in the line containing the `\hbar` or even somewhere BEFORE that line. Does the MWE that you posted in the previous comment generate that error for you? Or is it just in the real document?

Comment: yeah, the MWE does the same thing for me, but not for other people, apparently.